# Nginx: rewrite all subdomains to www except for one?

Tags: configuration, nginx, url-rewriting

Suppose I have a pair of servers that, due to the way things get deployed, need to use the same `nginx.conf`. One of the servers is at `staging.someserver.com`, and the other is at `www.someserver.com`.

What I want is a single rewrite line or an if condition that will redirect everything on the domain (mainly www and non-www on http, and non-www on https) to `https://www.someserver.com/`, and for `http://staging.someserver.com/` to redirect to `https://staging.someserver.com/`, but not to `https://www.someserver.com/`. How can I do this?

Comment: Essentially, what I need is the correct regex string that will do a rewrite for www and non-www, but not for staging. However, I can't figure out how nginx processes the request string.

Answer (score 1):

This is a trick on Nginx configuration : The first server block of HTTP block will be the "default" configuration.

So you can redirect in the first server block everything, and create another server block with your www. configuration !

Thats the best solution.

Comment: thanks for "This is a trick on Nginx configuration : The first server block of HTTP block will be the "default" configuration.
"!

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if this is strictly the best way to do this, but I figured something out:

```
server {
    listen 443 default deferred;

    # ...

    if ($host !~ (staging)|(www).*)
        rewrite ^(.*) https://www.someserver.com$1 permanent;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;

    # ...

    if ($host !~ staging.*) {                                   
        rewrite ^(.*) https://www.someserver.com$1 permanent;    
    }                                                           
    if ($host ~ staging.*) {                                    
        rewrite ^(.*) https://staging.someserver.com$1 permanent;
    }                                                           
}
```

Comment: It's not, [if is evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil). And [here is your case](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Server_Name).